# MAAS Region and MAAS Cluster Master on the same machine

Tags: networking, server, maas

I have installed MAAS with Ubuntu 14 server and I am trying to set up the cluster master. When I make any change to the cluster master interface I get this error 
Error: Unable to connect to cluster 'Cluster master' (7618447d-ff12-4d95-81ff-27562ae72a79); no connections available.

I have been looking for a solution but I am unable to find one. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am building a virtualbox cluster, and I hit the same problem today (that is how I found your question).  I suspect it had to do with how I modified the networks, adding a nic after the fact and swapping their order.  Unfortunately, the only way I could fix it was to reinstall from scratch.